# Encrypting MongoDB password

Tags: spring, mongodb, public-key, encryption-asymmetric

I'm using spring's mongo template to access my db,
I was wondering if it is possible to encrypt asymmetrically the password usage such that i'll provide the DB the one key, and I'll have the other.
(Encrypt only the authentication part, not the whole connection/data)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want x.509 authentication. Help on getting that setup is a little too broad for a single stack overflow question. There are various guides you can find with a Google search and for the nitty gritty details of what is happening under the hood and common issues I wrote a long [blog post](http://www.allanbank.com/blog/security/tls/x.509/2014/10/13/tls-x509-and-mongodb/).

If you really don't want the encryption of the "whole connection" (and I would strongly encourage you to reconsider that since it is basically free) you can use on the NULL cipher suites with the SSL connection. Configuring the client to offer only NULL cipher suites (and getting the server to accept them) will, again, require more details on your specific setup.

HTH - Rob

P.S. Just to be clear the authentication messages in SSL are done "in the clear". The contents of the messages contain portions that are asymmetrically encrypted (challenges and pre-master secret) but the bulk of the handshake exchanges are in the clear.